# Resize images using openCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, resize

I have the follow method to get all the images from a dir:

```py
def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()
    classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]
    width = 605
    height = 700
    dim = (width, height)


    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = os.listdir(Path)

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
            for Image in os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File)):
                # Convert the path into a file
                ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))
                # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
                LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0]))
        else:
            ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))    
            # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
            LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0]))
    return ImageCV, LabelList
```

But my images are bigger and a want to reduce its wxh to 605x700, then I tried to do something like This:

```py
imgR = cv2.resize(ImageCV[Image])
```

And it not works.. What can I do to resize all these images? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are all the images that you read of the same size?

Comment: there are 22 imgs (605x700) and 49 imgs (4288x2848)

Comment: It always helps to read the documentation for a method such as cv2.resize(). See the arguments needed. See https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to pass in the shape to `resize()` function of `cv2`.

This will resize the image to have 605 cols (width) and 700 rows (height):

```
imgR = cv2.resize(ImageCV[Image], (605, 700))
```

For more options you can read the documentation for [cv2.resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).

Also, I would suggest using python coding conventions like `imgR -> img_r`, `Image -> image`, `ImageCV -> image_cv` etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: It's something to do with your for loop. Try `for index, value in enumerate(list):` I can help if you post the code for it.

Comment: Must I delete this : for Image in os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File)):?

Comment: I'm not sure as to where you are adding `resize()` to your code. But if its in that loop change it to `for index,  Image in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):` . Now, you could access list items by `ImageCV[index]`.